# When struggling with an important course right before applying to grad school, is it better to withdraw or get a C grade?

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, statistics

I am a undergraduate economics student who is looking to apply to PhD statistics programs next year. I don't have the strongest math background because I started my undergraduate studies looking to go straight into the finance industry after graduation. I am currently taking a real analysis course as this is a prerequisite for any type of graduate study in statistics, and I am doing poorly. I think at this point the best I can do is a C+. Other than this course, I have excellent grades and I think I am a solid candidate for some of the "better" statistics graduate programs in the US. But, I feel that if I get a C in real analysis during my final year, I will be effectively disqualified from all PhD statistics programs.

So: would it be better to drop the course now, receive a W grade, and retake it next semester? Which is viewed worse by admissions?

Comment: Note that titles should ideally be questions (with a question mark), or at least give an indication of what the specific problem is. We discourage titles like "retaking a course" since someone with the same situation in future will be unlikely to find the post (and because posts with such titles typically don't contain a well-defined question at all, but that does not seem to be the case here). I've taken a stab at this, you can make further edits if needed.

Comment: Have a look at the stated requirements of the stats programs.